# Set of fields inside a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There are set of questions which could be answered with 'Yes' and 'No' and when any of the option is selected, more fields have to be shown.
So I have each question in a single `row` and when user selects an option I have to show all the child fields vertically. Child field div should appear in different background color.
What happening is that:

1. All the `childFields`are trying to fit into single row.
2. Background color of `div.childFields` is stretching to the width of row.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row row-padded">
        <p>Question: Are you 18 years old?</p>
        <p>Answer:</p>
        <div class="radio-inline">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio-inline">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios1" id="optionsRadios2" value="option1">No</label>
        </div>
        <div class="childFields">
            <p class="">Give full details here: </p>
            <label class="pocLabel">Details</label>
            <input type="text" name="city">
            <label class="pocLabel">Dates and Duration</label>
            <input type="text" name="city">
            <label class="pocLabel">Details</label>
            <input type="text" name="city">
            <label class="pocLabel">Dates and Duration</label>
            <input type="text" name="city">
        </div>
     </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.row-padded {
  padding-left:25px;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
div.childFields {
    padding:20px;
    background-color: #bbb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to resolve problem #1 by using the markup structure/classes as given in Bootstrap's documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

```
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
 <!-- ... --->
</form>
```

Regarding #2: If you do not want `childFields` to display like a block level element (i.e. taking the full width), make it `display:inline`. Another option is to assign a fixed width to it.